# Outlook add email account: requested operation failed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using MS Outlook 2007, under Windows 7.
I am trying to add a new email account.
I go through the process, I check "manually configure ...".
I enter all the info (it's an IMAP). The "test account settings" says it's all good.
I click NEXT and ...

THE REQUESTED OPERATION FAILED

No explanation, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Outlook in Safe Mode with networking, then create account and restart. Worked for me